# Avoid flicker when moving annotations in a MKMapView on iPhone

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

As far as I know, there isn't a way to move an annotation without removing & re-adding it to the MapView (Maybe I'm wrong).

Is there a way to prevent the MapView from being re-drawn between removing & re-adding the annotation? Right now the re-draw after removing the annotation causes a frame without the annotation, so it appears to flicker.

I need a solution that works in iOS 3.1 updates.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out how achieve flicker free annotation "updates" using the below code.  In a nut shell, you add your new pin FIRST, then delete the old one AFTER.  I haven't streamlined my code yet but you'll get the idea.

```
-(void)replacePin:(NSString *)title SubTitle:(NSString *)subTitle Location:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location PinType:(MapAnnotationType)pinType Loading:(BOOL)loading Progress:(float)progress
{
    //Find and "decommission" the old pin... (basically flags it for deletion later)
    for (MyMapAnnotation *annotation in map.annotations) 
    {
        if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            if ([annotation.title isEqualToString:title])
                annotation.decommissioned = YES;
        }
    }

    //add the new pin...
    MyMapAnnotation *stationPin = nil;
    stationPin = [[MyMapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:Location
                                              annotationType:pinType
                                                       title:title
                                                    subtitle:subTitle
                                                     loading:loading
                                              decommissioned:NO
                                                    progress:progress];
    [map addAnnotation:stationPin];
    [stationPin release];
}
```

Then AFTER, I make the call to search for and remove any decommissioned pins:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = nil;

    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        MyMapAnnotation* annotation = (MyMapAnnotation*)annotation;

        //your own details...

        //delete any decommissioned pins...
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(deletePin:) withObject:annotation.title waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
    return annotationView;

}
```

And finally, in the background get rid of the old pin:

```
-(void)deletePin:(NSString *)stationCode
{
    for (MyMapAnnotation *annotation in map.annotations) 
    {
        if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            if ([annotation.title isEqualToString:stationCode])
            {  
                if (annotation.decommissioned)
                    [map removeAnnotation:annotation];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

in iOS4

```
[theAnnotation setCoordinate:newCoordinate];
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks good. I really need a solution that works in iOS 3.1 though. I've edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: For those who are interested in why it works: Map Kit relies heavily on key-value observing. The MapView observes the title, subtitle and coordinate of its annotations and requests a new view form its delegate if a property changes. The annotations send  notifications when you change these properties. You can also manually send them using `[annotation willChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"];` and 
`[annotation didChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"];`. For more info on KVO see [the docu](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

Answer (score 1):

For 3.1 you'll have to hack. I'd see two possibilities, either trying to force change the coordinates of the current annotation by lurking around in the header files and accessing the memory directly, or fiddling with UIWindow and graphic contexts to try to avoid the drawing done in next runloop cycle to actually reach the screen.

Edit: a third alternative, which might be the easiest, is to do your own lightweight annotation implementation outside of MapKit..