# iOS Mapkit - Annotations disappear on map scroll/zoom

Tags: ios, annotations, hide, mapkit

On initial load, the annotations show just fine. But if I scroll the map, they all disappear and the code is only called for the user location, not the other annotations in the viewForAnnotation delegate method.

Plot Pins

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     ...Download Coordinates and Data from Web here...
     [self.mapView addAnnotation:pin];
}
```

Delegate Method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    //Player's Pin
    if([annotation class] == MKUserLocation.class) {
        return nil;
    }

    //Cluster Pin
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[REVClusterPin class]]){
        REVClusterPin *pin = (REVClusterPin *)annotation;
        if( [pin nodeCount] > 0 ){
            pin.title = @"___";

            MKAnnotationView *annotationView  = (REVClusterAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"cluster"];

            if( !annotationView ){
                annotationView = (REVClusterAnnotationView*)
                [[REVClusterAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"cluster"];
            }

            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cluster.png"];

            [(REVClusterAnnotationView*)annotationView setClusterText:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[pin nodeCount]]];

            annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
            return annotationView;
        }
    }
    //Player Pin
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[ZEPointAnnotation class]]){
        ZEPointAnnotation *pin = (ZEPointAnnotation *)annotation;
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pin"];
        if(!annotationView){
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
        }
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.draggable = NO;

        ...Create Pin Data Here...

        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Despite the two following observations, I still wonder if the problem rests elsewhere. Try commenting out this `viewForAnnotation` method temporarily. Does the user location beacon now work?

Comment: If nothing else, you should have `if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])`. You really should not test `class` with equality operator, especially since you're not assured that there isn't some subclassing that iOS might be doing in the background. I don't think that's the issue (as it should fall through to the final `return nil;`, but just an observation.

Comment: BTW, if `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` ever succeeded in returning a previously released `MKAnnotationView`, do you ever set the `annotation` property? Personally, in that `if (!annotationView)`, I'd suggest and `else` clause that sets `annotationView.annotation = annotation;`

Comment: @Rob I commented out the viewForAnnotation and it mapped out the annotations with default red pins. But they still all disappear when scrolling/zooming the map (and the user location "re-animates in"). I did update the isKindOfClass check, thanks. Lastly, by calling dequeReausable.. it will return nil on first load. Then the annotationView is created in that statement. After that, it will return the already created annotation...Unless I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: Oh and still having the same issue! So frustrating...

Comment: On the dequeue, imagine if you have four annotations, the first three of which have their annotation views visible at a given time. Then you pan, and only #2 and #3 are visible, then you pan a little further and #4 becomes visible. It's possible that the annotation view that was used for #1 will be dequeued and reused so you can quickly view #4. It's kind of like dequeue for `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`. Thus, if `dequeue` is successful, it's important to set whatever might have changed from annotation view #1 to #4 (generally only the `annotation` property).

Comment: On removing `viewForAnnotation`, as frustrating as the problem still being there, that's really good news. Eliminates that code from contention for the list of candidate issues. Got to be something else. Either keep removing stuff until the problem goes away, or alternatively, add map view with a few annotations to blank project and keep adding stuff until your problem manifests itself. Feel free to compress your project and share it with us (if you want and can) if you need diagnostic help.

Comment: @JamesHickman Hi, I know it has been more than 2 years but if you can remember the trick that got this issue work, can you share it? Or at least direct me to the right track? I am trying to do the exact same thing. I am using clustering so i have two different types of custom `MKAnnotationView`s. But they keep on disappearing and mixed up.

Answer (score -2):

remove animations. that will solve your problem