# iOS google map sdk user location image

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

1.It possible to change user location image in IOS google map sdk?

If yes, I must use accelerometer or something other way?

[image]

2.Can I change the radius of my location?

[image]

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293432/how-to-change-mkmapviews-user-location-blue-dot-to-an-image-of-choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answers are no and no.

As far as I can see from the official documentation, there seems to be no way to change the default user location dot. [There is an open issue about it](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5143&q=label%3aApiType-IosSDK&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal). You could hide the user location and draw your own annotation with an overlay of your own choice.

As for changing the radius, you can't do that either. That radius depends on the precision of the GPS signal, but you could draw your own overlays and hide the user location as stated above. However, I really don't see why you would do that.