# Replace blue dot in GMSMapView by an arrow - Swift

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, cllocation, gmsmapview

I use the Google SDK for an application iOS8 (Swift).
I want to replace the blue dot (my location) in a GMSMapView by an arrow witch rotate according to the orientation of the smartphone.
How can I do that?

**EDIT :**

I managed to see my arrow but I have three problems :

[image]

1 : The arrow is cut and I do not find as enlarge the area

*2 : The position of the arrow is not exactly on my location **I solve this problem by delete "0,5" :***

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, size.width, size.height)
```

*3 : The direction of the arrow is symmetrical to the original **I solve this problem by adding "-" before "degrees" :***

```
CGContextRotateCTM(context, CGFloat(DegreesToRadians(Double(-degrees))))
```

How to solve these problems ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Google Maps iOS SDK, seems there is [no way to replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22068447/4195406) the default user location icon. However the default icon already has an arrow to indicate which direction user is going (simply call `mapView.myLocationEnabled = true`).

A workaround is to put a marker on user's current position, and change the marker image based on heading.

Sample Code ([the full source code](https://github.com/ziyang0621/GoogleMapsCurrentLocationRotation-Swift/blob/master/GoogleMapSwift/ViewController.swift)):

```
    func RadiansToDegrees(radians: Double) -> Double {
        return radians * 180.0/M_PI
    }

    func DegreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> Double {
        return degrees * M_PI / 180.0
    }

    var GeoAngle = 0.0
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var marker = GMSMarker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
        var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        self.view = mapView

        marker.map = mapView

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
        var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
            longitude: newLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 15)
        (self.view as GMSMapView).animateToCameraPosition(camera)

        GeoAngle = self.setLatLonForDistanceAndAngle(newLocation)
        marker.position = newLocation.coordinate
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading!) {
        var direction = -newHeading.trueHeading as Double
        marker.icon = self.imageRotatedByDegrees(CGFloat(direction), image: UIImage(named: "arrow.png")!)
    }


    func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat, image: UIImage) -> UIImage{
        var size = image.size

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.5*size.width, 0.5*size.height)
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, CGFloat(DegreesToRadians(Double(degrees))))

        image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: -size.width*0.5, y: -size.height*0.5), size: size))
        var newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }

    func setLatLonForDistanceAndAngle(userLocation: CLLocation) -> Double {
        var lat1 = DegreesToRadians(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        var lon1 = DegreesToRadians(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

        var lat2 = DegreesToRadians(37.7833);
        var lon2 = DegreesToRadians(-122.4167);

        var dLon = lon2 - lon1;

        var y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2);
        var x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon);
        var radiansBearing = atan2(y, x);
        if(radiansBearing < 0.0)
        {
            radiansBearing += 2*M_PI;
        }

        return radiansBearing;
    }
```

The key step is to change image based on the degree come from the `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading!)` method.

You also need to make sure to add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in your `info.plist` file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive response. I have just 3 problems. I have edit my post. Do you know where these problems ?

Comment: My arrow is able to shown, not sure why yours is cut off. Seems you have solved yours 2nd and 3rd problem, the code I wrote definitely need some improvement, you might refer this post for different but similar approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173925/how-to-rotate-a-direction-arrow-to-particular-location

Answer (score 0):

The default blue icon of Google maps in iOS can be hide by setting

```
mapView.myLocationEnabled = FALSE;
```