# Custom user location dot in Google maps for iOS (GMSMapview)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

1. Is there an official way to set a custom user location dot in Google maps for iOS (GMSMapView)?
2. Is there a known way to "hack" it? Like iterating through all subviews and layers and fish the blue dot?
3. Even if you can't customise its appearance, can you control its z order index? When you have many markers, the little blue dot becomes hidden, and sometimes you want it to be visible at all times.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using Google Maps iOS SDK, seems there is no way to replace the default user location icon, a workaround is to put a marker on user's current position, you can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988038/replace-blue-dot-in-gmsmapview-by-an-arrow-swift/28997121#28997121) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to find the image on:

GoogleMaps.framework > Resources > GoogleMaps.bundle
OR
GoogleMaps.framework > Resources > GoogleMaps.bundle > GMSCoreResources.bundle

I did a quick search on those and the only associated file I found with that blue dot is GMSSprites-0-1x.

Please read the google maps terms and conditions because this might not be legal.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if Google has issues with updating the blue dot and accuracy circle with a custom color?
Since it can be done programatically and have the same effect...

Answer (score 5):

You can set the maps `myLocationEnabled` to `NO`. That will hide the default location dot. Then use an instance of `CLLocationManager` to give you your position. Inside `CLLocationManager` `didUpdateLocations` method you can set a custom `GMSMarker`. Set its icon property to whatever you want your dot to look like using `[UIImage imageNamed:]`. This will allow you to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: There is an example of this?

Comment: No,then problem comes when user starts moving here and there,then there comes more than one marker.

Comment: @G.Abhisek : You have to change position of marker.. you dont have to add marker on every movement

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

Disable the default Google Map current location marker (it's disabled by default):

```
mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = false
```

Create a marker as an instance property of the view controller (because a delegate will need access to this):

```
let currentLocationMarker = GMSMarker()
```

The `GMSMarker` initializer allows for a `UIImage` or a `UIView` as a custom graphic, not a `UIImageView` unfortunately. If you want more control over the graphic, use a `UIView`. In your `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` (wherever you configured the map), configure the marker and add it to the map:

```
// configure custom view
let currentLocationMarkerView = UIView()
currentLocationMarkerView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
currentLocationMarkerView.layer.cornerRadius = 40 / 4
currentLocationMarkerView.clipsToBounds = true
let currentLocationMarkerImageView = UIImageView(frame: currentLocationMarkerView.bounds)
currentLocationMarkerImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
currentLocationMarkerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "masterAvatar")
currentLocationMarkerView.addSubview(currentLocationMarkerImageView)

// add custom view to marker
currentLocationMarker.iconView = currentLocationMarkerView

// add marker to map
currentLocationMarker.map = mapView
```

All that remains is giving the marker a coordinate (initially and every time the user's location changes), which you do through the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` delegate.

```
extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let lastLocation = locations.last!

        // update current location marker 
        currentLocationMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)   

    }

}
```

The first few locations that the location manager produces may not be very accurate (although sometimes it is), so expect your custom marker to jump around a bit at first. You can wait until the location manager has gathered a few coordinates before applying it to your custom marker by waiting until `locations.count > someNumber` but I don't find this approach very attractive.