# How to change current GPS Point blue to black on Apple Maps?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-maps

How to Make Black color to blue GPS Point in ios using swift??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the `default view` for `current location` in `MKMapView`,if you wan to change it then you should hide `this current location` (i.e. by setting - `yourMapView.showsUserLocation` to `false`) and you can add custom `annotation` to that `latlong`, i mean custom image (black image) that you want to show instead of blue!

Take a look on below delegate,

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

if (!pinView) {

    MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];   
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation){
       customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myCarImage.png"];
    }
    else{
        customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mySomeOtherImage.png"];
    }
    customPinView.animatesDrop = NO;
    customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    return customPinView;

} else {

    pinView.annotation = annotation;
}

return pinView;
}
```

Reference : [This SO Post!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293432/how-to-change-mkmapviews-user-location-blue-dot-to-an-image-of-choice)