# How to toggle replace MKMapView's user location blue dot to an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

How to change `MKMapView` user location blue dot to an image and then image to blue dot?

**Example-** Suppose map has loaded with blue dot and I have a `UISwitch` (disabled) on that page initially. When user will enable switch I want to change blue dot to image and again if user will disable `UISwitch` then I want to change image to blue dot without loading map again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293432/how-to-change-mkmapviews-user-location-blue-dot-to-an-image-of-choice

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dheeraj but it is not fulfil my requirement. please read above example description carefully.

Answer (score 1):

to change the icon / or to show the blue Dot (the default) refer to to: [How to change MKMapView's user-location blue dot to an image of choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293432/how-to-change-mkmapviews-user-location-blue-dot-to-an-image-of-choice)

to TOGGLE the image/dot to be used for the location, call map `view.showUserLocation = NO; view.showUserLocation = YES;` to make the view refresh the 'dot annotation view'