# Move custom annotation to display user location

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, core-location

I have replaced the blue dot for user location in `mapview` with my custom annotation view, How can I make my custom annotation to follow user's location like the default blue dot does? When I replace the blue dot with my custom annotation or simply create `MKAnnoationView`, it just stops moving with the user. In `viewForAnnotation` delegate method of mapview , I am doing

```
pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                  initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newgreen2.png"];


        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"]; 

return pinView
```

This is showing a pin with newgreen2 image but it does not move, but if I return nil in this delegate method, blue dot appears by default which moves with user's location. Is there any trick to mimic this behavior of default blue dot for user location for my custom annotation view? I have noticed that `viewForAnnotation` is called only once and then blue dot automatically starts tracing the users location.

Is there any way by which I can tell my annotation view to follow the user's location?

Answer (score -1):

We have two links that could be helpful here
[How to change MKMapView's user-location blue dot to an image of choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293432/how-to-change-mkmapviews-user-location-blue-dot-to-an-image-of-choice)

And

[Avoid flicker when moving annotations in a MKMapView on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514359/avoid-flicker-when-moving-annotations-in-a-mkmapview-on-iphone)

Please check it out.

Comment: I have posted this question after doing my homework and I have already gone through all these links and failed. In one of your link, the OP has said below the accepted answer that he has successfully replaced blue dot with his desired image but it has stopped moving.